# Making a Prediction from a qda function in r

Tags: r, machine-learning, model

I am attempting to make a QDA Model in r. My code for the Model is below, and the model works (It makes a prediction for the training data and creates a working confusion matrix.

```
Model3=qda(TARGET_FLAG~KIDSDRIV+PARENT1+MSTATUS+CAR_USE+TIF+CAR_TYPE
           +CLM_FREQ+REVOKED+MVR_PTS+ URBANICITY +SQRT_TRAVTIME +SQRT_BLUEBOOK+SQRT_INCOME 
           +EDUCATION+JOB, data = train)
Model3
summary(Model3)
summary(Model3)
predmodel.train.qda = predict(Model3, data=train)
table(Predicted=predmodel.train.qda$class, TARGET_FLAG=train$TARGET_FLAG)
predmodel.test.qda = predict(Model3, newdata=modtest)
table(Predicted=predmodel.test.qda$class, TARGET_FLAG=modtest$TARGET_FLAG)
Model3=qda(TARGET_FLAG~KIDSDRIV+PARENT1+MSTATUS+CAR_USE+TIF+CAR_TYPE
           +CLM_FREQ+REVOKED+MVR_PTS+ URBANICITY +SQRT_TRAVTIME +SQRT_BLUEBOOK+SQRT_INCOME 
           +EDUCATION+JOB, data = data)
Model3Prediction <- predict(Model3, type = "response")
data$Model3Prediction=Model3Prediction$class
confusionMatrix(data$Model3Prediction, data$TARGET_FLAG)
```

This produces the desired effects, but when I apply the model to the Test Data i get the following error:
"Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, P_TARGET_FLAG, value = list(class = c(1L,  :
replacement has 2 rows, data has 2141"

```
test$P_TARGET_FLAG <- predict(Model3, newdata = test, type = "response")
```

How do I get the model to predict the value of my test data?

Answer (score 0):

I hope, you are already splitting your data in train and test -
`trainset = (data)`
`test = Data[!trainset,]`

Once you are done, Try to use below code.
Model3 <- qda(TARGET_FLAG~KIDSDRIV+PARENT1+MSTATUS+CAR_USE+TIF+CAR_TYPE +CLM_FREQ+REVOKED+MVR_PTS+ URBANICITY +SQRT_TRAVTIME +SQRT_BLUEBOOK+SQRT_INCOME +EDUCATION+JOB, data = data, subset=trainset) qda.preds <- predict(Model3 , new =test) 'cm.f <- table(test$predictor, qda.preds$class) 'cm.f

Comment: So the first set of code, I had a set of training data (a sample of 80% of the original training set) and a model testing set (the other 20% of the training data set) used in the first part. The second code portion is my attempting to apply the model from above to a separate data set for testing with no already existing Y.

Comment: And I verified there are no NAs in either data set